# Equivalent definition of normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

A subgroup $N<G$ is called normal if $gN=Ng  ,\forall g \in G$. My book then says this is equivalent to $gN\subset Ng ,\forall g \in G$.

How do I see this? One way is obvious, but how do I show that if $gN\subset Ng ,\forall g \in G$, then $gN=Ng, \forall g\in G$?

I have tried to say, let $g \in G, n \in N$. Then $gn= n' g$ for some $n' \in N$
From there I have to somehow show $ng= g n''$ for some $n'' \in N$. Could someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* If $gN\subseteq Ng$ for all $g \in G$, then it's true for $g^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks lhf that did the trick!